# Moved /images, errors in log from those images, solution?

Tags: htaccess

I moved the /images folder on a site, which contained uploaded images, to a new containing folder.  I was able to update all the images used by the site itself to use the new path, but there's still a lot of links out there in user generated content both on the site and elsewhere that points to that old folder location.  Is there a solution to those errors, maybe an htaccess rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly is an .htaccess rule you can use. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/new/images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Give that a shot and let us know how it works.

Comment: Giving this a shot, thank you.  If it clears up the errors over the next day or two I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "search & replace" tool in the CP under Tools > Data which you can do to make the change to the entries directly. Back up the DB first of course.